# Can we get the list of apps programmatically in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

Is that possible to get the list of apps and their names in windows phone using c# code ? And links to launch any app installed in phone ?

Comment: In WP7 - I'm 100% sure you can't. Not sure about WP8, but don't think it changed.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get the list of applications that are installed on the Windows Phone that are published by someone **other than the publisher of the calling application**.

**There is a way**, however, to get the list of applications that are installed on the device and are originating from the publisher of the caller app. Here is [what I am talking about](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207014%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<Package> apps = Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher();
apps.First().Launch(string.Empty);
```

This required your app to run on a Windows Phone 8 device.

Answer (score 0):

With the current Windows Phone SDK you don't have access to that information.

There are some apps that allow you to supply your Live Id and then they will go into your profile and get info about the apps you have installed, but that will actually allow them to do whatever they want with your Live Id, so I wouldn't go that way...