# Get List of installed windows apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I want to get the list of installed uwp application in the desktop.I want to make it within uwp application.Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have look at similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448832/can-we-get-the-list-of-apps-programmatically-in-windows-phone

Comment: Ya It's getting list of installed package bt while uploading to store it's shows error as "Remove Restricted Capabilities"

Comment: I want to get list of installed Win32 Application in the System.Is it possible to achieve it in UWP?

Comment: Please follow the steps below **Important** section in [Special and restricted capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#special-and-restricted-capabilities) to request access to a restricted capability before submitting your app to the store. And for a UWP store app, it can't get  list of installed Win32 application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [PackageManager.FindPackagesForUser(String) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240968) to find all packages installed for for the current user in UWP apps like following:

```
PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager();

IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package> packages = packageManager.FindPackagesForUser("");
```

This method returns an enumerable collection of [Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.package.aspx) objects. Each [Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.package.aspx) object in this collection contains information about the package, including but not limited to its name, publisher, version, and install location.

But please note that **To use this method in a UWP app, we need to declare restricted capability `packageQuery` in app's package manifest.**

```
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

  ...

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="packageQuery" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

For more info, please see [Special and restricted capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#special-and-restricted-capabilities).

Comment: Is there any way to get installed win32 applications in the UWP?